# Why this computed property is showing changes (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, computed-properties

I am changing properties using some buttons. When I click the buttons the data is updated in the UI, even the `computed1`, but not the `console.log("computed1")`. I think it's because I am changing its properties and not the entire object. But if it's not triggered, why the UI is updated ? Could you explain me ? I couldn't find something like this in the documentation.

Code:  https://jsfiddle.net/1hr7cy5d/

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: function() {
    return {
      item: {
        aaa: 'aaa',
        bbb: 'bbb',
        ccc: 'ccc'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computed1: function() {
      console.log("computed1");
      let item = this.item
      return item;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    method1() {
      console.log("method1")
      this.item.aaa = 'xxxx';
    },
    method2() {
      console.log("method2")
      this.item["bbb"] = 'yyyyy';
    },
    method3() {
      console.log("method3")
      this.$set(this.item, "ccc", "zzzzz")
    },
    method4() {},
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <button @click="method1()">method1</button>
  <button @click="method2()">method2</button>
  <button @click="method3()">method3</button>
  <button @click="method4()">method4</button>
  <pre>{{item}}</pre>
  <pre>{{computed1}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: You're watching for changes on `this.item` but making changing to `this.item.PROP`. If you mutate `this.item` directly then computed1 will run, else, it doesn't see it as a change and won't run. https://jsfiddle.net/1hr7cy5d/4/.

Comment: but why `{{computed1}}` is showing changes?

Comment: @DennisMartinez but then why does it update the display? Shouldn't it re-run the computed function then if it's updating the display?

Comment: `computed1` isn't returning a new value but a reference to `this.item` because in javascript objects are by reference, not by value. You're telling Vue to print `this.item` and you're updating properties of `this.item`. It won't rerun the function because `this.item` hasn't changed but rather a property on `this.item`. Vue doesn't support nested computed properties. You may want to try `watch` with and option of `deep`

Comment: @DennisMartinez you should post as an answer :)